# COALESCE and REPLACE Function

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to replace all null values in my query with '' as our interface won't accept NULL as an entry.   Ive run into a piece of my code where im using the REPLACE function to take away DASHES in a SSN.   How can I tell the system to give me '' for the NULL values in the SSN column and still do the REPLACE function for non null entries SSN.

```
select distinct clients.CLIENT_ID_1 as SourceMRN,
 '' AS HMOMEMBER,
 '' as IDXMRN,
replace(clients.CLIENT_ID_2,'-','') as PatientSSN,
```

i was thinking something along the lines of something like this but it doesnt work.

```
CASE IF clients.client_id_2 is null then '' 
ELSE replace(clients.CLIENT_ID_2,'-','') as PatientSSN,END
```

Also am wondering how I can replace NULL with '' for other columns where I see null values would it be the same answer as the above question?

```
Select clients.last_name,
clients.first_name,
case if clients.middle_name is null then '' else clients.middle_name,
```

Thanks again for any help

Comment: It looks like you already know the answer: COALESCE. What have you tried?

Comment: replace(COALESCE(clients.CLIENT_ID_2,''),'-','') should work also COALESCE(clients.middle_name,'')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `isnull` function to replace null values:

```
replace(isnull(clients.CLIENT_ID_2, ''),'-','') as PatientSSN
```

The `coalesce` function can also be used in the same way. The only difference between `isnull` and `coalesce` is that `isnull` is specially intended to replace a null value so it only takes two parameter.

You can also use a `case`, then it would be:

```
case
  when clients.client_id_2 is null then ''
  else replace(clients.CLIENT_ID_2,'-','')
end as PatientSSN,
```