# combine CONCAT() and COALESCE() to generate JSON in MySQL

Tags: mysql, json, null, coalesce

I'm building small JSON blocks from functions and I need to filter null values while quoting non-null values like this (**MySQL 5.0**, so no built-in JSON functions):

```
COALESCE(CONCAT('[', 
    group_concat(
        CONCAT('{ "key": "', REPLACE(a.val, '"', '\\"'), '"}') 
        SEPARATOR ', ')
, ']'), 'null') AS jsonval
```

which outputs something like this (this is a value to be embedded in a full JSON block):

- with values: `[{"key": "foo"}, {"key": "bar"}, {"key": "baz"}]`
- without values (NULL): `null`
- with empty string: `[{"key": ""}]`

For each `a.val` I want to add an entry to my list but have the string `null` instead of the full list if no value is found. It works pretty well, but I need to handle empty strings as well as `NULL` values as null in resulting JSON.

`REPLACE()`, `CONCAT()` and `COALESCE()` work pretty well together for null values, but empty strings are not detected, how can I handle NULL and empty string the same way ?

I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26680893/coalesce-and-replace-function) about striping null values, i'm looking for the opposite.

Comment: Why are you generating JSON from within SQL code? Generally you shouldn't be doing that (because that's an application/data-transfer concern, not a database operation).

Comment: I shouldn't be using MySQL 5.0 either... Business requirements! This JSON should not be transferred but used for reporting/maintenance purpose, we can't add an external tool for export.

Comment: related after edit : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12818897/mysql-group-concat-vs-coalesce-concerning-null-values

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just iterating your idea!

```
COALESCE(CONCAT('[', 
    group_concat(
        CONCAT('{ "key": ',COALESCE(CONCAT('"', REPLACE(a.val, '"', '\\"'), '"'), 'null') ,'}') 
        SEPARATOR ', ')
, ']'), 'null') AS jsonval
```

After your edit:

```
COALESCE(CONCAT('[', 
    group_concat(
        CONCAT('{ "key": ',
            CASE WHEN a.val IS NULL THEN 'null'
                 WHEN a.val = ''    THEN 'null'
                 ELSE CONCAT('"', REPLACE(a.val, '"', '\\"'), '"')
            END
        ,'}')
    SEPARATOR ', ')
, ']'), 'null') AS jsonval
```

Comment: tried that too... the problem is REPLACE(NULL, 'foo','bar') will return an empty string, not NULL so COALESCE will never trigger

Comment: Work fine in my tests. May be a configuration. select COALESCE(CONCAT('foo',REPLACE(NULL, 'foo','bar'),'bar'),'nUlL') as result;
+--------+
| result |
+--------+
| nUlL   |
+--------+

Comment: OK my bad, Bogus empty strings in database.

Comment: works fine but I think there is a typo, you should remove second "CASE", I can't edit your post (not enough characters)

Comment: Yes! sorry, glad to help! nice question

Comment: for my specific need, I just have to return NULL instead of 'null' to exclude the whole bloc from output

Comment: well, that's fine. If you need help, let me know.